# Is "head range" critical when selecting a hot water recirc pump?

Tags: plumbing, pump

I've been looking at hot water recirculation pumps for some time now. In looking at [an on-line review page](https://plumbinglab.com/best-hot-water-recirculation-pump-reviews/) (I know, take them all with a grain of salt) I saw one that lists the "Head Range" for the pumps they've reviewed. This "head range" runs from 0 (for all of them) to as little as 5 feet for some and 36 feet at the high end.

Does this head range indicate the maximum vertical difference between where the pump is located (in the basement) and where the highest point in the loop is (on the 2nd floor)?

If this is a critical bit of information why does it seem to be so difficult to find in the information I've been able to come up with on line? (i.e. I've looked at the literature available at several on-line retailers and none seem to list "head range".) Additionally, it seems I'm extremely limited in my choices since I've got 9' ceilings on the first floor, so at a *minimum* I'd need about 15' of "head range" if my understanding is correct.

Comment: The more of these reviews I read, the more I'm convinced they're being written by ChatGPT. Doesn't matter if it's for a recirc pump, a power tool, or a car. Darn Skynet is taking over. Why can't people learn from the movies??!?!??!!?

Comment: Head for pumps means how high they can pump, but that is usually just by themselves.  In a pressurize system do not know if it is the same, but recirculating pumps can be placed at the top of the system as well as the bottom.

Comment: Good points about installing it at the top of the loop and city water pressure, @crip659. I'd considered the upstairs install a few times, but forgot about it when looking at these reviews. I've got plenty of utility space to install it upstairs, but it would be between the guest bedroom & bath, and I'd rather not have a noise source there if it can be avoided. I doubt any of these are particularly loud, but... Plus downstairs is a root cellar, so a leaky/failed pump drains onto a concrete floor and flows to the sump instead of inside wooden walls.

Comment: I have two for an outdoor wood furnace.  They are almost silent, need to put your ear on them to hear.  Leaks are another matter, but you have pipes there also, so the increase risk is quite minor.  One does about 15 feet on pressure system going up(hot water tank), the other is non pressurize going down and back up about 13 feet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to find the information because it doesn't matter in the least. There is no head required in a closed loop. The weight of the water on the side of the loop going down "pulls" the water on the side of the loop going up. It's all balanced*.

(* I'm lying. It's only balanced if all the water is the same temperature. If one side of the loop is hot and one side is cold, water will circulate slowly with no pump at all due to the difference in density between hot and cold water. But that's to your advantage.)

I use a pump with a 0-10 foot head range. The pump is in the basement and the highest crossover valve is on the second floor, well beyond the 10 foot head range. Doesn't matter. The water circulates with great gusto, and it works great.

Head would matter in an open loop such as in pumping to an open faucet. Or if the pipes were full of air and not truly a solid closed loop. But not for a normal hot water circulator.

Answer (score 2):

The head in a closed loop is entirely "dynamic head" - that is, the friction from moving the water through the pipe. There is no static head, so the elevation does not matter, just the effective length (actual length plus extra length for elbows and tees.) A long single level house and a tall multi-story house work the same for that.

As such, a pump with greater head capacity will settle on a faster rate of flow when activated (since what happens in a closed loop is that the pump pumps until the flow rate causing the friction matches the rate the pump can manage.) You might want that on a long loop with lots of twists and turns.

This does not, of course, come for free - generally, a pump with greater head capacity will also use more power. But a lower-power lower-head-capacity pump will recirculate the water slower, and a higher-power higher-head-capacity pump will recirculate it faster.